# What's a good Open Source or free ticket tracking system?

Tags: open-source

I'm looking for a good free or Open Source ticket tracking system that can be used to help manage support tasks and clients in a computer repair style situation.

Ideally, this software would be something like Zen Desk or the like.

What ticket tracking systems do you use? What tips would you have on selecting such a system?

Comment: Duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/904/what-is-a-good-open-source-issue-tracking-system

Comment: Not exactly, I see his question as an issue tracking system for end users to report problems. Mine is more for software geared towards staff in a help desk style situation to create and organize tickets for issues.

Answer (score 9):

Check out RT: Request Tracker, by Best Practical at http://bestpractical.com/rt/.  It's free and open source and works pretty well from what I've heard/read from others.  We use a custom-built system internally, so I don't have personal experience with RT.

Answer (score 7):

Wikipedia has a [Comparison of issue tracking systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_ticket-tracking_systems)

Answer (score 4):

[Roundup](http://roundup.sf.net) is pretty decent and easy to hack on if you know a bit of python.

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend [Spiceworks](http://www.spiceworks.com/), it's free (unobtrusive ads) and while I only tested for a few days it seems pretty good. I found it to be easy to use and have a lot of features.

Comment: SpiceWorks is awesome.  It is totally free but it is not open source.  You cannot modify the source but can deploy as needed.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend trying Vermis, a new, open source issue tracking system.

Check out the online demo: http://vermis.ognisco.com/demo/

Answer (score 0):

We use [OnTime](http://www.axosoft.com), which is primarily driven for software development tracking, but the incident tracking is really good for our needs (we do some software development too).  I like it because it has an API and the SQL data is easily accessible so you can create custom reports and views on the data.  You can get a single user license for free.  If you need more or think you'll need more in the future, then this might not be for you.  You can eval it though, so maybe it can help you figure out which features you definitely need and don't need.  We tried out a bunch of open source software and none of them really worked well, they were not complete enough.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I've used [JIRA](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/) and also [Bugtracker.NET](http://ifdefined.com/bugtrackernet.html). JIRA is really pro but for non Open Source project has a cost, BugTracker.NET is Open Source and really easy to setup and use.
It had a couple of security bugs in past releases that were fixed so I'm using that in one of my projects (not a big one) with success.

Answer (score -1):

I've had good experiences with [JIRA](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/).

Comment: Jira is neither open source nor free.