# Best practice email setup for "support@", "info@", "sales@" etc... accounts on OS X Server

Tags: email, email-server, mac-osx-server

I'm sure I'm overlooking something as this should be routine... But I'm wondering how admins are setting up generic accounts like "support@domain.com" & "info@domain.com"? With OS X Server you can create aliases in a user's mail account and those messages will automatically be forwarded to said user... But I want a separate IMAP (or POP) acct that could be monitored by multiple clients. Do I really need to create a full user in our system & Open Directory for each of these accounts when all we need is email only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have these setup as aliases for mailing lists, so for example support@domain.com is an alias for support@lists.domain.com. This means that user accounts can be added to/removed from the list as necessary.

Comment: Didn't even think to do that. Good idea! But how does your workflow prevent multiple responses to the same inbound message?

Comment: Replies are cc'd back to the list an well as to the original message. Very occasionally two people will reply at exactly the same time, but not often.

Comment: trying to understand how you you did this. did you set up a "user" called "support" on OS X Server and then forward all mail to that account to support@lists.domain.com? sorry for the confusion. At first pass I'm finding it hard to set the mailing list (Mailman) to accept a message from ANYONE but forward only to subscribers of the list. Currently each message wants to be moderated...and I certainly don't want customers who send email to support@domain.com to be automatically added (or ever added) to this mailing list!?!

Answer (score 1):

A ticketing system might be the answer if you need to make sure that each question to your generic aliases is answered, and answered by only one person (as you suggest in your comments). Most decent ticketing systems have multiple queues and can attach different email addresses to that different queues; you can then give your employees/users access to and notifications from the relevant queues.

There are a few ServerFault questions about good ticketing systems: [ticketing for support types](https://serverfault.com/questions/947/whats-a-good-open-source-or-free-ticket-tracking-system) and [ticketing for non-developers](https://serverfault.com/questions/904/what-is-a-good-open-source-issue-tracking-system).

We use [OTRS](http://otrs.org/) for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, but a tool has launched not too long ago to do exactly that: https://frontapp.com

You can add any "role based" shared inbox, with its own IMAP account, and have it checked by many users in your team.