# What are some good hosted issue tracking systems for non-developers?

Tags: helpdesk

This question is similar to [Good Open Source issue tracking systems for non-developers](https://serverfault.com/questions/904/what-is-a-good-open-source-issue-tracking-system-for-non-developers)
 but in our case, we would prefer a hosted solution.  The users are end-users, on the low end of computer literate, non developers.  We have around 5 support people and 50 or so end users.  We are interested in simple issue tracking, like a printer being down, as opposed to project or bug tracking.  Email integration is desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying [Mojo Help Desk](http://www.mojohelpdesk.com).  I'm not sure what it lacks compared to the more expensive solutions, but it seems pretty full featured for what I'm looking for and the price is right starting at $12 / month.  I'll update this answer in a month or so.

UPDATE 1/3/2011:  We are currently using Mojo and are happy with it.  We've been live for about six weeks.

Answer (score 3):

I like RT, and you can get it as a service: http://www.gossamer-threads.com/hosting/request_tracker.html

Comment: Very interesting, +1 for the answer, seems on the expensive side for us at a starting price of $125 a month.

Comment: +1 for RT, see if you can find it hosted cheaper. Its open source so its not too hard to run it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I can advise you to take a look at this one - http://bontq.com

Comment: Looks like it's more aimed at projects and bug tracking / new feature requests than pure help desk, but thank you.